# Fake: What is the difference between fileset selectors: !!, ++ and !+

Tags: f#-fake

There are different fileset selectors in FAKE. What is the difference between these: !!, ++, !+?

I found these examples:

Example 1:

```
// Filesets
let appReferences  = 
  !! "src/app/**/*.csproj" 
    ++ "src/app/**/*.fsproj"
```

Example 2:

```
// files
let appReferences =
  !+ "./src/**/*.fsproj"
    |> Scan
```

Example 3:

```
let filesToZip =
  !+ (buildDir + "/**/*.*")
    -- "*.zip"
    |> Scan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!+ "./src/**/*.fsproj"
  |> Scan
```

is obsolete and replaced by !!

```
-- "*.zip"
```

excludes files from the fileset above.